# Adding Row of Values To Matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I am relatively new to R and so I think I have relatively simple question. If you have a matrix, m.

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
[3,]    7    8    9
```

I want to add the values of a row, t, to the matrix m.

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    3    4
```

resulting in the new matrix p...

```
3 5 7
6 8 10 
9 11 13
```

I was hoping that there would be a generalized way to do this instead of doing something like m[1,]+2. Thank you for your help and time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may try this

```
m1 + m2[col(m1)]
```

Or

```
sweep(m1, 2, m2, `+`)
```

#### data

```
 m1 <- matrix(1:9, 3, 3, byrow=TRUE)
 m2 <- t(2:4)
```

Comment: The first option worked perfectly. Thank you for your quick response!

Answer (score 1):

You can try also this way of recycling, if your row is a vector as input:

```
m1 = matrix(1:9, 3, 3, byrow=TRUE)
m2 = 2:4

t(t(m1) + m2)

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    3    5    7
#[2,]    6    8   10
#[3,]    9   11   13
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an alternative, you could also turn row t into a matrix using the below, which tells R to repeat the row for however many rows m has:

```
t <- matrix(rep(c(2,3,4), length(m[,1])), nrow = 3, ncol=3, byrow = TRUE)
```

Then

```
new_m <- m+t
```

Data for original m:

```
m <- matrix(c(1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 8, 3, 6, 9), nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
```

Comment: Whoa, a matrix called `t`? That letter already refers to the matrix transposition function.

Comment: Whoops, you're right. I was going along with the example, but yes, call it something else. Maybe new_t.